# NUMA Get Current Node/Core

Tags: c++, linux, numa

I'm using libnuma on Linux. My threads should be aware of the node/core they're running on. Is it possible to get the current threads's node/core somehow? I've been through the documentation, but I didn't find such a function...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found this solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <utmpx.h>

int main(void) {
  printf("CPU: %d\n", sched_getcpu());
  return 0;
}
```

Then, if you need the node of the cpu, you can use numa.h:

```
int cpu = sched_getcpu();
int node = numa_node_of_cpu(cpu);
```

Comment: sched_getcpu() is the most stable way to get cpuid. Since, you were explicitly looking for both cpu and node id, that's why I replied with getcpu(). Actually, getcpu() don't have libc wrapper, you need to use syscalls() system call. And, this is another of reason  sched_getcpu() is better than getcpu(), along with portability issues.

Answer (score 10):

A lighter-weight approach is to make use of the RDTSCP instruction (on x86 systems that support it -- it will be listed as "rdtscp" in the "flags" field of /proc/cpuinfo).

The RDTSCP instruction returns the time-stamp-counter value in a pair of 32-bit registers (%eax and %ebx), but also returns the contents of the IA32_TSC_AUX MSR in the %ecx register.  The contents of the IA32_TSC_AUX MSR are theoretically arbitrary, but every version of Linux that recognizes the "rdtscp" processor flag pre-loads the IA32_TSC_AUX register on each logical processor with an encoding of both the logical processor number (bits 11:0 of %ecx) and the "node number" (bits 21:12 of %ecx).  The instruction grabs the TSC and the IA32_TSC_AUX register atomically, so you are guaranteed that the TSC value and the IA32_TSC_AUX value were obtained on the same core (which is critical if the TSC has different offsets on different cores).

The nice thing about this approach is that RDTSCP is a user-space machine-language instruction, so you don't need to interact with the kernel or any libraries.  Overhead is under 50 cycles on recent systems.  The routine I use is:

```
unsigned long tacc_rdtscp(int *chip, int *core)
{
    unsigned long a,d,c;
    __asm__ volatile("rdtscp" : "=a" (a), "=d" (d), "=c" (c));
    *chip = (c & 0xFFF000)>>12;
    *core = c & 0xFFF;
    return ((unsigned long)a) | (((unsigned long)d) << 32);;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to use [`getcpu()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getcpu.2.html) system call. As man page says:

> determine CPU and NUMA node on which the calling thread is running

So, this should serve your purpose. Needs to include `<linux/getcpu.h>`, with kernel version greater than 2.6.19 and for x86_64, i386 arch.

Comment: Thanks, that should work, but I didn't manage to run it. There's no <linux/getcpu.h>, and the documentation says it should be directly invoked with syscall(). So I tried the other solution with <utmpx.h> and sched_getcpu()...