# In windows get NUMA Node of current thread

Tags: c++, windows, numa

I would like to find the NUMA node for the current thread in Windows.

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16862620/numa-get-current-node-core) for Linux but I need it in Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Window's NUMA support is covered on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363804(v=vs.85).aspx).  You can query [GetCurrentProcessorNumber](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683181(v=vs.85).aspx) to get the processor number of the current thread and pass the result to [GetNumaProcessorNode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683205(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: thanks. GetCurrentProcessorNumber was what I was missing.